# InRequestScope disposes entitycontext for DelegatingHandlers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-web-api

When I bind my context as `InRequestScope`, the context is disposed when the code in  DelegatingHandler is called (instantiated in Application_Start and executed before controllers are initialized). If I use InTransientScope, then it works but I want 1 context for everything. Based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187446/400861), it is the correct way to have 1 context.

Global.asax

```
static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.Bootstrapper.Kernel;
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiKeyHandler(kernel.Get<IApiService>()));
}
```

Bindings

```
//if i remove InRequestScope here, everything works.
kernel.Bind<EntityDatabaseContext>().ToMethod(context => new EntityDatabaseContext()).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();

//repositories
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Application>>().To<Repository<Application>>().InRequestScope();

//services
kernel.Bind<IApiService>().To<ApiService>().InRequestScope();
```

So Whenever `SendAsync` gets called in ApiKeyHandler, the context was already disposed. But when a controller is called (after calling the ApiKeyHandler), the context is fine. I'm not too sure what is going on. If it cannot work with InRequestScope, how can I accomplish it like how the answer in the linked question did it? 1 context InTransientScope and all others in InRequestScope?

Answer (score 1):

Using a transient or singleton scoped context for your message handler gives you the limitation that all the entities will be cached for the message handler. E.g. if an entity is changed/deleted or a new one is added your message handler will never adapt to that change. This can be ok in some scenarios where the data is never changed.

If you need to operate on up to date data that will change you can't use these scopes. But `InRequestScope` means that you have to create a new instance of the service every time using a factory (see [factory extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory)). That way you can have the context in request scope.